# Conservation of energy in a uniform electric field

Tags: homework-and-exercises, energy-conservation, electric-fields, potential-energy

Say you place a positively charged particle between two plates with an uniform electric field between them. The particle will accelerate towards the negatively charged plate with a constant acceleration, and the work done on the particle by the field is defined by:

$$\Delta W = qE \Delta x$$

Where $\Delta W$ is the work done, $q$ is the particle's charge, $E$ is the uniform field strength and $\Delta x$ is the distance the particle has moved.

From my understanding, $\Delta W$ should be equivalent to the particle's loss of absolute electrical potential energy and it's gain in kinetic energy. However, as an answer to a textbook question with this setup, $\Delta W$ was defined as the gain in EPE and also the gain in KE.

However, isn't that impossible, because if the particle gains $\Delta W$ in KE and in EPE then it will gain $2\Delta W $ in overall mechanical energy, which is impossible because only $\Delta W$ work has been done?

Is there an error in my textbook, or am I making a conceptual error somewhere?

Comment: The particle loses EPE and gains KE. It does not gain both.

Comment: That's what I thought. So then the textbook has an error.

Comment: If the textbook says that both EPE and KE increase in this situation then Yes the textbook has an error.

Answer (score 0):

In electrostatics, the work done *on* the charge in moving it from position $A$ to position $B$ is

[image]

Here, we choose the mechanical force $Fm$ such that it balances the electric force $qE$ at each point along the path. What does this say about the kinetic energy?

Comment: https://physics.stackexchange.com/help/notation